# Packaging electron app using electron-packer - folders shown not existing

Tags: electron

I am trying to package my electron app . Follwing the instruction [Here](http://www.juxt.com/pov/thoughts/building-native-desktop-apps-with-web-tech). I added an object to my package.json like below

```
"osx-package": "node_modules/electron-packager/cli.js 
                    ./build/bin --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=0.34.0 --overwrite"
```

When i run

```
npm run osx-package
```

I received the messgage below

> Packaging app for platform darwin x64 using electron v0.34.0 Wrote new
>   app to /...../binary-build-darwin-x64

Below is what i can see from by sublime text.

[image]

However, when i visit the folder, i can only see three files . Myapp(i.e execuatble ) , licence file and version file. I unhidden hidden files , still couldnt see my files as expected. However, the files were still shown in the directory in sublime . Clicking my app throws an error saying can't find an electron framework etc. Please what am i misssing  ? How do i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Did your try running it via the console with `npm start`?

After packaging the OSX app, the following files should be created:

- LICENSE
- LICENSES.chromium.html
- MYAPP.app
- version